# A quick "What am I?" riddle

Tags: riddle

> I'm always dropped, but never picked up.
>
> I'm covered with copper in particular, though I describe many types of metal
>
> Winners do me, losers are me.
>
> My innards taste like meat; my outside looks bent.
>
> **Who am I?**

Comment: why is this downvoted? this is a nice riddle, solved by a nice solver. nothing's wrong with this, and please be nice to new users! thanks! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you

> BEAT?

I'm always dropped, but never picked up.

> “Drop the Beat” is a popular phrase, but “Pick Up the Beat” is not.

I'm covered with copper in particular, though I describe many types of metal

> Copper wire is used in Beats headphones; although any malleable metal can be beat.

Winners do me, losers are me.

> Winners beat others, losers are beat by others.

My innards taste like meat; my outside looks bent.

> The interior/innards of bEAt are the same as those of mEAt. The exterior/outside of BeaT are the same as those of BenT.

Comment: i believe this is the correct answer, well done! #RealEliteGuest +1 ;)